# Proof of tensor characterisation lemma in Riemannian Geometry by Lee

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

Is there any book that proves the following theorem? The proof that is mentioned is only for covariant tensors and the second part is not done at all.
[image]

[image]

I think having Prop. B1 the proof of the seond part is rather short, isn't it? :

"$\implies$":

If $F$ is a $C^{\infty}$-mult.-linear map, then by Prop.B.1, $F$ can be identified with a (k+1,l)-tensor, namely, for some $\omega_{k+1}$,

$\omega_{k+1}((F\omega_{1},...,\omega_{k},v_{1},...v_{l}))$

"$\Longleftarrow$":

Given a (k+1,l)-tensor $\sigma$ Prop.B.1 says that $\Phi^{-1}[\sigma]$ is a $C^{\infty}$-mult.-linear map.

**Proof attempt for Proposotion B.1:**

First let's look hat the special case mentioned in excercsie B.2.

Let $\Phi:End(V)\to T^{(1,1)}(V),A\mapsto\Phi[A](\omega,v):=\omega(Av)$.

**Claim:** $\Phi$ is bijective

*- Injective:*

Suppose $\Phi[A]=\Phi[B]\iff\omega(Av)=\omega(Bv)\iff\omega(A-B)v)=0$, by linearity of $\omega$. Since this is true for all $\omega\in V^{*}$ and $v\in V$, it is also true for $dx_{i},e_{i}$, i.e. basis vectors of $V^{*}$ and $V$ respectively.

$(A-B)e_{j}$ is a vector with entries $a_{ij}-b_{ij}$.Thus,

$0=dx_{i}((A-B)e_{j})=a_{ij}-b_{ij},\forall i,j\iff A=B$.

*- Surjective*:

Since we deal with finite dimension surjectivity follows from the fact that $\Phi$ is injective.$dim V=dim Im(f)+dim\ker(f)$

"The longer way":

Let $\sigma\in T^{(1,1)}(V)$. We need to find $A$ such that $\Phi[A]=\sigma$.

Let's look at $\Phi[A](\omega,v)=\omega(Av)
                                =\omega(\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}(\Sigma_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}v_{j})e_{i})
                                =\Sigma_{ij}a_{ij}v_{j}\omega(e_{i})
                                =\Sigma_{ij}a_{ij}v_{j}\Sigma_{k}\omega^{k}dx_{k}(e_{i})
=\Sigma_{ij}a_{ij}v_{j}\omega^{i}$

Now let's look at $\sigma(\omega,v)=\sigma(\Sigma\omega^{i}dx_{i},\Sigma v^{j}e_{j})=\Sigma_{ij}\omega^{i}v^{j}\sigma(dx_{i},e_{j})$.

We want $\Phi[A](\omega,v)=\sigma(\omega,v)\iff\Sigma_{ij}a_{ij}v_{j}\omega^{i}=\Sigma_{ij}\omega^{i}v^{j}\sigma(dx_{i},e_{j})\iff\Sigma_{ij}(a_{ij}-\sigma(dx_{i},ej))v^{i}\omega^{j}=0$.

Since both $\omega,v\neq 0$ there have to be non-zero coefficients. Hence, $a_{ij}=\sigma(dx_{i},e_{j})$.

Therefore by the above calculations let $A:=(\sigma(dx_{i},e_{j}))$. Then the pretty much same calculation as in the very first one shows that $\Phi[A](\omega,v)=\sigma(\omega,v)$.

**General case:**

Since we still deal with finite dimensions it suffices to show injectivity:

Let $\Phi:Mult(V^{*}\times...\times V^{*}\times V\times...\times V,V)\to T^{(k+1,l)},\eta\mapsto\omega_{k+1}(\eta(\omega_{1},...,\omega_{k},v_{1},...v_{l}))$

Suppose $\Phi[\eta]=\Phi[\tau]\iff\omega_{k+1}(\eta)=\omega(\tau)\iff\omega_{k+1}(\eta-\tau)=0$ (the arugments are omitted).

Now as in the special case consider $\omega=dx_{i}$. Since $\eta-\tau\in V$ $dx_{i}(\eta-tau)=(\eta-\tau)_{i}$,i.e. the i-th component.

Thus, $0=dx_{i}(\eta-\tau)=(\eta-\tau)_{i}\iff \eta=\tau$. Hence, $\Phi$ is injective.

Comment: Have you looked at [LeeSM, Lemma 12.24] as written just after the title of Lemma B.6?

Comment: @Didier Yes. There only the covariant case is covered.

Comment: It is straightforward to extend the proof to the general case. A shortcut would be to use a Riemannian metric and the provided musical isomorphisms

Comment: @Didier Okay, but I am more interested in the second part.

Comment: I don’t understand the difficulty here. The proof should be verbatim the same, substituting $1$-forms for vector fields when you evaluate the multilinear map. Please say specifically where you run into difficulties.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'll try: If I plug in k covectors and l vectors into F don't I get section of M,i.e. a vector field?  How do I define a (k+1,l)-tensor using F and vice versa, i.e. given a (k+1,l)-tensor field, how do I get the map F? Don't I need Prop. B1 for that?

Comment: A section of $M$? I can't see the difficulty in defining $\mathscr F$. Can you do this for $k=\ell=1$? Ultimately, you still need to show that $C^\infty$-linearity gives you dependence just on the values at the point, etc.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am not sure if we are talking about the same part of Lemma B.6. I thought "X(M)" are sections of M.

Comment: That doesn't even make sense. $\mathscr X(M)$ is the space of vector fields on $M$, which you can view as the space of sections of the *tangent bundle of $M$*.

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean. Sorry, but I don't see how $F(\alpha,v)$ defines a tensor? For me $F(\alpha,v)\in X(M)$.  Using Proposotion B1, which identifies Mult(V*x...xV*xV...V,V) with T(k+1,l)(V), I think it can be identified with a (k+1,l)-tensor. I think the isomorphism could be $\alpha_{k+1}(\Phi(\alpha_{1},...\alpha_{k},v_{1},...,v_{l}))$, but I haven't looked into it further.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why Ted is so confident in comments that the proof is exactly the same is because we have the following more general lemma, which generalizes both the covariant and contravariant cases. This is one of those times where generalizing makes everything simpler.

Below, $\Gamma(E)$ is the $C^\infty(B)$-module of sections of $E$.

---

**Lemma.** Let $E \to B$ and $F \to B$ be finite rank smooth real vector bundles (over a paracompact base). Every $C^\infty(B)$-linear map $\Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(F)$ is induced by a vector bundle map $E \to F$, and conversely.

**Proof.** Of course, a map of vector bundles $E \to F$ induces a $C^\infty(B)$-linear map of sections $\Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(F)$ by post-composition. Now suppose that $\phi : \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(F)$ is $C^\infty(B)$-linear. We want to define a map $T : E \to F$ for each $e \in E_b$ by letting $\sigma \in \Gamma(E)$ be some section such that $\sigma(b) = e$ and then declaring $T(e) := \phi(\sigma)(b)$; it suffices to show that $T(e)$ defined this way is independent of the choice of section $\sigma$. In turn by $\mathbb{R}$-linearity it suffices to show that $\phi(\sigma)(b) = 0$ whenever $\sigma(b) = 0$.

We first claim that $\phi$ must be *local*, in the sense that if $\sigma \in \Gamma(E)$ is such that $\sigma = 0$ on some open neighbourhood $U \subset B$ of some $b \in B$, then $\phi(\sigma)(b) = 0$. But this is easy to see: pick a $C^\infty(B)$ function $f$ such that $f(b) = 1$ and $f = 0$ outside $U$. Then we must have $f \sigma = 0$ and so (by $\mathbb{R}$-linearity)
$$
\phi(\sigma)(b) = f(b) \phi(\sigma)(b) = \phi(f \sigma)(b) = 0,
$$
as claimed. Again by $\mathbb{R}$-linearity, this implies that if two sections $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ agree on a neighbourhood of $b \in B$ then $\phi(\sigma)(b) = \phi(\sigma')(b)$.

Now fix any $\sigma \in \Gamma(E)$ and $b \in B$ for which $\sigma(b) = 0$, and pick an open neighbourhood $U$ on which $E$ and $F$ are each locally trivial. On $U$ there then exists a basis of sections $\{\alpha_i\}$ of $E$. This means that (on $U$)
$$
\sigma(x) = \sum_i g_i(x) \alpha_i(x)
$$
for some functions $g_i \in C^\infty(U)$. Note that since $\sigma(b) = 0$ this means that $g_i(b) = 0$ for all $i$. Choose some extension of the $a_i$s to all of $B$, and likewise extend the sections $\{\alpha_i\}$ to all of $B$ (in both cases this is possible by paracompactness of $B$, though the sections $\{\alpha_i\}$ need not be linearly independent outside of $U$). Then $\sigma$ and $\sum_i g_i \alpha_i$ agree on $U$ and therefore (by locality, then $C^\infty(B)$-linearity, then since $g_i(b) = 0$)
$$
\phi(\sigma)(b)
= \phi\left(\sum_i g_i \alpha_i\right)(b)
= \sum_i g_i(b)\phi(\alpha_i)(b)
= 0.
$$
This completes the proof.

---

The lemma recovers your question by letting $E$ be the tensor product of $k$ copies of the tangent bundle of $M$ with $l$ copies of the cotangent bundle of $M$, and letting $F$ be the rank 1 trivial bundle $\mathcal{E}_1 = M \times \mathbb{R}$ over $M$ (since then $\Gamma(\mathcal{E}_1) = C^\infty(M)$).